# How to add samesite none option in django settings file

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I used Django 2.0.2 version. I tried to process google authentication in Django project. I got the token but I will pass URL and token. it return 404 error. I need to add samesite='none' in Django settings project. Where to add I don't know and I tried to add many ways but still it's throwing 404 error. How to fix it.

**Settings.py**

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django_cookies_samesite.middleware.CookiesSameSite',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

So, I added samesite.middleware.CookiesSameSite middleware. but still I facing this warning **A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://stats.XXXX.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. It has been blocked, as Chrome now only delivers cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details** How to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Follow [this](https://pypi.org/project/django-cookies-samesite/) instructions, and set

```
DCS_SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'
```

at `settings.py` right after MIDDLEWARE list

Also you need establish ssl connection to your dev server or use some outdated browser which allows using SameSite cookie policy with `None` attribute and without attribute `secure`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some cookie still haven't the attribute. You can try with this flag in your settings:

```
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE_FORCE_ALL = True
```